# Mysql Galera Cluster best practice size for big DB?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, cluster-computing, galera

I have a 10 mysql nodes in Galera Cluster(4CPU and 8GB RAM). But now have some issue with 5** timeouts, site have about 30k requests page per hour throws cache(with cache about 150k, but I think it's not matter for mysql cluster). I have a option to change 10 nodes to 5 nodes, but more powerfull(8CPU and 16GB RAM), it would be better? MysqlTuner recommending about 11GB RAM, but I dont know it's correct or no.
Database size about 10GB with few tables 3GB+ size btw.
I would be grateful for any help

Comment: Why have you gone for 10 nodes? This is exceptionally large. 5 does sound like a more manageable number though I'd try to get it running on only 3. What MariaDB/Galera version are you running? How is it tuned (mariadb config)? What is the `show global status`? Have you you tuned your server to make use of the CPUs you have? Are the basic SQL statements tuned to use indexes correctly? Is your entire 10G of database active a single time or just a portion of it?

Comment: Also `SHOW VARIABLES;`  Are they CPU-bound or I/O-bound?  8 QPS is quite low unless they are terribly long-running queries.  Let's see a slow query, plus `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 11G` should be good.